# Determine the volume of the parallelepiped spanned by the given vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, inner-products, cross-product

The vectors u,v and w span a parallelepiped of volume V  0 in the three-dimensionalspace.  Consider the vectors

u′=u+v−w

v′=u−v−2w

w′= 2u+v+w

i)Determine the volume of the parallelepiped spanned by the vectors u′,v′and w′

ii)Do the vectors u′,v′,w′ have the same orientation as u,v,w?

---

This is my working for part (i)

Volume of (u',v'w') = (u' x v' | w')

u' x v' =

= (u+v-w) x (u-v-2w)

= (u x u) + (u x-v) + (u x-2w) + (v x u) + (v x-v) + (v x -2w) + (-w x u) + (-w x -v) + (-w x -2w)

=-(u x v) -2(u x w) + (v x u) -2(v x w) -(w x u) + (w x v)

=2(v x u) - (u x w) - 3(v x w)

Now that we have (u' x v') we just have to take the dot product with w'.

So, [ 2(v x u) - (u x w) - 3(v x w) ] \cdot (2u + v + w) = -3u(v x w) *** I didnt write the multiplication working for this one.

So I got -3u(v x w) for the volume of the parallelepiped of u', v' and w', but is this correct? Also I need some help with part (ii) if possible. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The volume of the parallelepiped spanned by three vectors $\mathbf{u,v, w} $ is given by the absolute value of the determinant

$V = | \begin{vmatrix}\mathbf{ u }, \mathbf{v} , \mathbf{w} \end{vmatrix} | $

Now the vectors $\mathbf{u',v', w'} $ are related to $\mathbf{u,v,w}$ as follows:

$\begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{u'}, \mathbf{v'}, \mathbf{w'} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}, \mathbf{w} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 &&1&&2 \\1 && -1 && 1 \\-1&&-2&&1 \end{bmatrix}$

Hence, the volume of the parallelepiped spanned by $\mathbf{u',v',w'}$ is

$V' = | \begin{vmatrix} \mathbf{u', v', w'} \end{vmatrix} | =  | \begin{vmatrix} \mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}, \mathbf{w} \end{vmatrix} |\hspace{6pt} |\begin{vmatrix} 1 &&1&&2 \\1 && -1 && 1 \\-1&&-2&&1 \end{vmatrix} | $

The first term on the right hand side is just $V_0$, and the second term evaluates to $|-7| = 7 $

Hence,

$V' = 7 V_0 $

For (ii), obviously the vectors $\mathbf{u',v',w'} $ do not have the same orientation as $\mathbf{u,v,w}$.

Comment: Thank you so much! That is so clear. I dont know what I did with my working lol. How to algebraclly show that u′,v′,w′ dont have the same orientation as u,v,w? Cheers

Comment: $u',v',w'$ will have the same orientation as $u,v,w$ only if $u' = \alpha u, v' = \beta v, w' = \gamma w $ where $\alpha \gt 0 , \beta \gt 0 , \gamma \gt 0 $, which is not the case here.

Comment: Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is an invertible linear map, two bases $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$ and $\{Av_1, \dots, Av_n\}$ determine the same orientation when $\det(A) > 0$, and determine opposite orientations when $\det(A) < 0$.

Comment: Excellent way to look at it! Thank you Mason :)